# How to use Mapping Variable in Target Update Override in informatica

Tags: etl, informatica

I'm trying to Update the Primary key(defined at informatica level) through target update ovverride.

I'm using update strategy to mark the record for update and in target update override i'm using varaible in where clause to update the old pk with new Pk like below

```
Update employee set emp_id=:tu.empid where emp_id= $$emp_id
```

`$$emp_id` is informatica mapping variable which holds the old pk value. When i run the mapping got error as

```
"Missing Expression"
Update employee set emp_id=??? where emp_id=
```

Which i beleive that informatica is not able to expand the variable value.

Could you please suggest what i'm doing wrong here. I have checked, mapping variable is correctly set.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do. if you run `Update employee set emp_id=??? where emp_id=$$emp_id ` in a database it will fail because  the param isnt defined in database. But in your SQL, you are upding a key column based on same column. This doesnt make any sense. Could you pls give more details on what you are trying to do.

Comment: This is just a pk column in informatica not in Database. and when the query which is wrote runs the variable value will be replaced by the actual at run time.  You can assume my requirement as " when an record for same employee is inserted into the table twice then the pointer should always point the latest record loaded in a table for same employee. Employee id will different . so instead for adding one more record to table i'm trying to update the employee id of the same old record. because that's the only change in new record. Above scenario is just for example for an diff actual Scenario

Comment: so, best idea would be - do a lookup into target on key column and update the employee id based on that - or let informatica do a DD_UPDATE to update all rows/ or single column.

Comment: We can't update the Key column using DD update. That's why i was using Target update override.

Comment: sorry i misread. emp id is the PK. Do you have natural key like emp_number  so you can change the override sql like this `Update employee set emp_id=:tu.empid where emp_number =:tu.emp_number `. if thats not possible, then you can delete and load.  if thats not possible, you can update all rows by making a constant column as key in informatica target definition(not a very good idea).

Comment: Used SQL Transformation to update.